# Add google.ie to IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, google-search

After recently reinstalling windows I now find that iegallery does not offer the create your own search provider any more - I get a 404 if you use the old link.

How can I add google.ie to IE9, only options searching iegallery are .com, .co.uk but no .ie

I had a brainwave to search the registry and found the entry for it.
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>Internet Explorer>Search Scopes` and find the entry for the google search url.

Answer (score 3):

(Based on [user104752](https://superuser.com/users/104752/user104752)'s suggestion)

### How to change the URL used in the Google Search add-on for Internet Explorer 9:

- Open the **Registry Editor**.

  [image: Registry Editor]
- Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` **>** `Software` **>**  `Microsoft` **>** `Internet Explorer` **>** `SearchScopes`
- Find the Google Search Add-on.

  [image: Google Add-on]
- **Double click** on `URL`, and edit the string.

  [image: Edit String]